# What does "so choose" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> Under the extra-inning rules, each half inning beyond regulation is started with a runner on second base. The runner is either the ninth batter due to bat in the current inning, or a pinch-runner if the batting team **so chooses**.

I see this sentence in [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/minor-league-team-makes-impossible-possible-thanks-wild-rule-162414074.html). "**So choose**" seems to be an idiom. I also found another example on [this site](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/11253-so-choose-to):

> I have two free concert tickets for tomorrow. We can see the concert at 7 pm and still be home in time to catch mom and dad before they leave. If you are not into it, just let me know and I can still sell the tickets in a split second. We can still watch the concert on TV if you **so choose**.

It has an explanation about the phrase:

> 'If you so choose" is used when a person is given an option of choosing between different things.

But with that limited explanation, I still can not get the phrase thoroughly. Can someone help to elaborate it based on the given examples above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a more succinct way of expressing "you can do X if you (want/choose/decide) to do X."

> ...or a pinch-runner if the batting team so chooses.

Can be reworded as

> ...or a pinch-runner if the batting team chooses to do so.

Or

> We can still watch the concert on TV if you so choose.

can be reworded as

> We can still watch the concert on TV if that is your choice.

Comment: So, in the second context, I am not clear what 'your choice' is?

Comment: @dan my choice is to "watch the concert on TV".  The immediate antecedent of the "if you so choose" phrase.

Comment: Can this structure be applied to other words? Like, so want, so decide, so like,....